# If a corresponding homogeneous system of an inhomogeneous system has non-trivial solution, the inhomogeneous one has infinitely many solutions.How?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

In the [book](http://hive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of Linear Algebra by Werner Greub, at page 87 section 3.7, it says that

> If a corresponding homogeneous system of an inhomogeneous system possesses only the trivial solution, the
>   inhomogeneous system has a solution for every LHS, i.e the $B$ matrix
>   in $Ax=B$.If the homogeneous system has non-trivial solutions, then
>   the inhomogeneous one is not solvable for every choice of $B$, and if it is solvable, it has infinitely many solutions.

But how can the inhomogeneous have infinitely many solutions, if it is solvable, I could't understand.

Comment: If $Ax = B$ and $Ay = 0$ for some $y \neq 0$, then $A(x + cy) = B$, for any scalar $c$ .

Comment: @DavidSchneider-Joseph you are right. I have never thought to consider the solution of the homogeneous one.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidSchneider-Joseph By the way, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: As a nice follow-up exercise, see if you can prove that $\{x + y : Ay = 0\}$ contains *all* the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Ax = B$ and $Ay = 0$ for some $y \neq 0$, then $A(x + cy) = B$, for any scalar $c$.

Conversely, suppose $Ax = B = Az$. Then define $y = z - x$, and we have that $z = x + y$ for some $y$ such that $Ay = 0$.